# calling stored procedure is too slow in Sybase ASE 15

Tags: stored-procedures, sap-ase

I'm new at Sybase.
Currently I'm having problem with executing stored procedure in it.

My procedure structure is like this :

@query = dbo.fn_funtingA()..
 exec(@query)

In the procedure above, I get a query by calling function and then execute the query.
If I particulary execute the query, it just takes 1~5 sec.
But when executing the procedure,
it takes more than 2~3 mins at the line of exec(@query) which I knew by procedure debugging.

What could be a problem for that result?
What should I check to solve the problem?

Is that an issue about procedure cache size?
(The options I changed after installing ASE are 
 - Dump tran  with no_log 
 - sp_dboption dbname,"ddl in tran", true
)

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[stored]` and `[procedures]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[stored-procedures]` tag, nor do `[sybase]` and `[ase]` mean the same thing as `[sybase-ase]`  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: Same here, at least I'm not alone :/